# Angular 7 - One function with multiple dropdowns

Tags: angular, function, angular7

I have custom dropdowns that I am trying to figure if there's a way to make on function call and not trigger all of them at once.

I understand there are options out there that can do dropdowns, however, the team I'm working with provides the design of the dropdown and we need to make it function.  With that said, I'm sure I've been doing it the long way and you smart people can help me simplify the process.  As it stands now, for each `dropdown/select`, I create its own function to toggle a class called active.  When it is active, the user can see the choices to select.  When the class is not there, then it appears to be an input box.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="required">Which option do you want below? </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="select-group dropdown {{optionIsActive}}">
      <div class="drop-group-text select" <b>(click)="toggleOption()</b>">
        <input id="option_choice" name="Option Choice" value="Please Choose">
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of optionChoice | wfsort">
            <ng-container *ngIf="!item.isHidden">
              <a (click)="selectDropdown(item.value)">{{item.label}}</a>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="submitted && optionChoice.length>0" class="alert alert--danger">
        <span class="error">This field is required. <span class="icon-chevron-up"></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
optionIsActive = '';
optionSelection = [];
submitted = false;
optionChoice = [];

constructor(private data: DataService) {
  this.data.getData.subscribe(response => dropDownData(response))

  dropDownData(data) {
    data.filter((v) => {
      v.id === 'xyz' ? this.optionChoice = v.dataStuff : '';
    });
  }

  toggleOption() {
    this.optionIsActive === '' ? this.optionIsActive = 'active' : this.optionIsActive = '';
  }

  selectDropdown(data) {
    this.optionSelection.splice(0, 1, data);
    (document.getElementById('option_choice') as HTMLInputElement).value = data;
  }
}
```

Long story, short - the key functions are `toggleOption` and `selectDropdown`.  Is there a way to make that function for all dropdowns without triggering all of them at once or having to create a function for each dropdown?

Comment: Try to reshape the question a bit clearer, maybe a screenshot of the UI? personally finding it hard to understand what you're trying to do but maybe that's just me, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

After some research and playing, it seems a structural directive met my need.

I was trying to make my dropdowns work solely via component but the directive allowed all of my dropdowns work independently with minimal code as opposed to creating a function for each dropdown element.